# Где ошибка в коде?  [Закрыт]

Tags: клиент-сервер, android, java, json, сервер

Заранее прошу прощения, если это окажется некорректный код, но ничего лучше "собрать" не получилось.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "http:");
        getRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        // Use GZIP encoding
        getRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); //
        try {
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(getRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response
                        .getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null
                        && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                }
                // convert content stream to a String
                String result = readStream(instream);
                instream.close();

                Log.i("JSON", result);
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                view.setText(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String readStream(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Не понимаю в чём причина. Если ЭТО можно исправить, подскажите, что где поменять. Если нет, то у меня есть конкретные вопросы, на которые не смогла найти ничего вразумительного...
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: отформатируйте код, для начала

Comment: что исправить? где ошибки?

Comment: да, не хватает логов...

Comment: launching has encountered   error occurred during the build

Comment: Gorets? спасибо за исправление!

Comment: Разобралась - всё работает )))! Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 1):

Помоему вы ищете это:

```
public XMLParser() {}

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
```

это совершенно рабочий код.

Comment: Kerins_Sataier,заменила только Post на Get, не срабатывает, пишет тоже самое при попытке запуска. В Manifeste что-нить особенное прописывать нужно?

Comment: права на интернет

Comment: Доколе??? Ставлю на AsyncTask

Comment: Gorets, права прописаны.
rasmisha, что именно ДОКОЛЕ? AsyncTask, в смысле думаешь что без него не запускается??? А что поэтапно нельзя всё это реализовывать?

Comment: Попробуйте то что тут описано http://www.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=157

Comment: Я когда писал программу запроса на сервер и получал в ответ xml использовал AsyncTask, а в нём писал

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
    {


     //Document doc;
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(params[0]); // getting XML
            doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
      return null;
     }
     ........
    }

Comment: тут вызыв таска

<pre>//Click,execute my task
public void onclick(View v) {
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute(wikiURL);
      }<code>

Comment: Kerins_Sataier, а что AsynckTask работать не будет? Я пока к проекту не подключаю, делаю в "черновике"?

Comment: Будет если правильно его напишите.
Тут описано всё что для этого нужно:
http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html

Comment: @s01nyshko если у вас таргет >=3.x то в основном потоке с интернетом не будет работать

Comment: rasmisha, а как будет если больше 3.х?

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что на это ответить. Вообще читайте гайды на developer.android.com, много интересного написано (хотя бы http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html )